# Error sending request to URL after logging into website (Python-request)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying send a request to a URL after logging into a website using requests. The URL is a child of the initial website.

[Here is the code so far](https://github.com/Tudor0404/Stackoverflow-Help/blob/master/Requests/Request%20login). Any help is great, thanks.

Comment: after logging in, just use the `session` variable like, `new_request = session.get(whatever_url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution for your [code sample](https://github.com/Tudor0404/Stackoverflow-Help/blob/master/Requests/Request%20login): You have to set cookies and auth.

Here the working code:

```py
from requests import Session

# Create headers dict.
headers2 = {
    # Your headers.
}


Post_Login_URL = 'http://parents.netherhall.org/'
Request_URL = 'https://parents.netherhall.org/parents/students/?admissionno=011161&page=homework'
payload = {
    'username': 'your_username',
    'password': 'your_password'
}


with Session() as session:
    # Send post request to login.
    response = session.post(Post_Login_URL, headers=headers, data=payload)
    cookies = dict(response.cookies)
    # print(post.text) # Page source.
    response = session.get(Request_URL, headers=headers, auth=(r'your_username', 'your_password'),
                           verify=False, cookies=cookies)
    print('Logged in successfully:', response.ok)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked really well. Will this work on another computer with he same headers(after editing the username in a header)?

Comment: Probably not, because in the headers there is your cookie. You should change them.

Comment: Would I be able to retrieve the headers using selenium? As I can login using selenium to get the  headers as a one of.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible. To do that, you should set a proxy like BrowserMob-Proxy or alternatively, you could use Selenium-Wire and Mobilenium, modified versions of selenium.

Comment: I tried using selenium-wire, but it would detect the header when searching for it using the example.